# How can I create a function that combines list/array rows/columns/elements in arbitrary sized array/list?

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x, numpy, iteration

Afternoon.  I'm currently trying to create a function(s) that, when given an array or list and a specified selection of columns/rows/elements, the specified columns/rows/etc are removed and concatenated into a  array/list-much in this fashion (but for arbitrary sized objects that may or may not be pretty big)

```
a = [1 2 3       b=['a','b','c' 
     4 5 6          'd','e','f'
     7 8 9]         'g','h','i']
```

Now, let's say I want the 1st, and third columns.  Then this would look like

```
  a'=[1 3         b'=['a', 'c'
      4 6             'd',  'f'
      7 9]            'g', 'i]
```

I'm familiar with slicing indices and extracting them using numpy-so I guess where I'm really hung up is creating some object (a list or array of arrays/lists?) that contains columns/whatever (in the above i choose the first and third columns, as you can see) and then iterating over that object to create a concatenated/combined list of what I've specified(i.e.-If I'm given an array with 127 variables and I want to exact an arbitrary amount of arbitrary columns at a given time)

Thanks for taking a look.  Let me know how to update the op if anything is unclear.

Comment: If you have list of list , you can convert it into a numpy array and use scipy to delete a column or a row

Comment: Do you mean numpy?

Sorry-I think I may have done a crappy job explaining my goal. I'd prefer not to have to go into the program and hard code which columns I want or don't want (right now I'm working with an array that has some unwieldy dimensions for such)..  Ideally I want to create a function(who excepts a tuple as an argument).  I'd like to be able to specify an arbitrary amount of arbitrary columns in the tuple and perhaps store them in a list-and then iterate over that list to combine the elements perhaps (I'm not sure how to do it the best way)

Comment: Indexing takes lists and tuples.  The values don't have to be 'hard-coded'.  Lists require iteration for anything beyond slices, but arrays have 'advanced indexing'.  Generally it is easier to select items than to delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this different from advanced indexing

```
In [324]: A = np.arange(12).reshape(2,6)
In [325]: A
Out[325]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [326]: A[:,[1,2,4]]
Out[326]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  4],
       [ 7,  8, 10]])
```

To select both rows and columns you have to pay attention to index broadcasting:

```
In [327]: A = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
In [328]: A[[[1],[3]], [1,2,4]]      # column index and row index
Out[328]: 
array([[ 7,  8, 10],
       [19, 20, 22]])
In [329]: A[np.ix_([1,3], [1,2,4])]   # easier with ix_()
Out[329]: 
array([[ 7,  8, 10],
       [19, 20, 22]])
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing

---

The index arrays/lists can be assigned to variables - the input the the `A` indexing can be a tuple.

```
In [330]: idx = [[1,3],[1,2,4]]
In [331]: idx1 = np.ix_(*idx)
In [332]: idx1
Out[332]: 
(array([[1],
        [3]]), array([[1, 2, 4]]))
In [333]: A[idx1]
Out[333]: 
array([[ 7,  8, 10],
       [19, 20, 22]])
```

And to expand a set of slices and indices into single array, `np.r_` is handy (though not magical):

```
In [335]: np.r_[slice(0,5),7,6, 3:6]
Out[335]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 3, 4, 5])
```

There are other indexing tools, utilities in `indexing_tricks`, functions like `np.delete` and `np.take`.

Try `np.source(np.delete)` to see how that handles general purpose deletion.

Comment: thanks!  much appreciated.  I'll start with practicing this.

is it possible to assign the elements to variables/indices in a sequence using some sort of inbuilt function that can concatenate the rows or columns regardless of how many are initially called (without have to declare variables for them in the body of your code block)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a double list comprehension

```
>>> def select(arr, rows, cols):
...     return [[el for j, el in enumerate(row) if j in cols] for i, row in enumerate(arr) if i in rows]
... 
>>> select([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]],(0,2),(1,3))
[[2, 4], [10, 12]]
>>>
```

please note that, independent of the order of indices in `rows` and `cols`,
`select` doesn't reorder the rows and columns of the input, note also that
using the same index repeatedly in either `rows` or `cols` does not give you duplicated rows or columns. Eventually note that `select` works only for lists of lists.

That said I advise you in favor of `numpy` that's hugely more flexible and
extremely more efficient.

Comment: thanks for the reply!  i'll start playing with this right now.

are you familiar with how to do the analogous with numpy?  thanks again!

Comment: W/r using `numpy`, see [hpaulj](http://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43484491/2749397). Their answer is so much better and detailed than my  `numpy`'s answer that I'm going to remove it (my preceding answer, that is).

Comment: thanks again-I can still learn a bit from your answer as well though!